# I need a straight forward way to automatically resize images as they are uploaded to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have a mobile app that is currently uploading images from the app to Google Cloud Storage. The problem is, the original files are quite large (which i still want to keep), so when viewing them in the app via the public url, it takes a long time to download.

I would like to, as images are uploaded to Cloud Storage, resize them, and use the smaller image's url to preview them in the app.

I recognize the solution is probably to use App Engine and the Python Images API, but I can't quite figure out how to connect App Engine to Cloud Storage (I am not familiar with App Engine).

Any guidance would be appreciated.
-Zach

Answer (score 3):

You can configure object change notifications (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) and create an App Engine app that resizes each incoming image and produces a smaller image. One common way to do this is to have separate incoming and live buckets, so the live bucket only contains images that have already been resized.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following workflow in Java - it must be the same in python:

(a) When a user is ready to upload an image, I make a call to App Engine backend to request an upload URL. This upload URL is created using BlobstoreService and using the Cloud Storage bucket name. You also pass a callback handler like "/imageupload".

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/imageupload", UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("myBucket"));
```

(b) The client receives the upload URL and inserts it as the URL into the upload form. When the form is submitted, the original image is uploaded directly into the Cloud Storage bucket.

(c) When upload is complete, Cloud Storage will call your callback handler that you provided (e.g. "/imageupload"). This call will include information about uploaded object, including its Cloud Storage object name and size.

Once you receive this call back, you can create an Image object from this information and pass it to the Images API for resizing. Then you can save resized images.

The best part is that App Engine and Cloud Storage work seamlessly in this workflow as long as everything is under the same projectID. You don't need to worry about authentication.